# Laravel Inertia check current route In JSX file?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes, client-side, inertiajs

I need to check current route in one of my .jsx files to display a specific component, is there a way to imitate Laravel's Route::is() feature?

For now I do the following:

```js
// helpers.js

export function IsRoute(query) {
    return query == window.location.pathname;
}
```

Edit: I know I can directly check the url path but if there is a more convenient way to do this I would love to know

Laravel Version: 10.44.0
PHP Version: 8.3.3
Inertia: ^0.11.1
inertia-react: ^0.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this: [Ziggy, Laravel routes in JavaScript](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy)

You can use it with React, Vue or vanilla JS. Among others it has [route().current()](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy?tab=readme-ov-file#check-the-current-route-routecurrent) function that can check what is current route.